# How to find and replace a string including wildcards in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: wildcards

I have a Calc spreadsheet which I copied and pasted from Wikipedia. It has a bunch of citation links in the form of "[num]".
Something like "some data I want to keep [1] [12]".

How do I use Find and Replace (CTRL+H) to replace everything that starts with a "[" and ends in a "]" with a "wildcard" or any integer between them?

I've tried the: Other options > Wildcards check box, using "." as any character wildcard, but that doesn't work.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The help system explains how the "wildcards" work in regular expression. Agreed, it is not simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Search-and-replace dialog and check "Regular expressions". Then search for `\[\d+\]`. This will search for the literal `[`, followed by one or more digits (`\d`), followed by the literal `]`.

The backslashes are necessary to escape the `[` and `]` which would otherwise be interpreted as part of the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you kindly.